# Making A PHP variable from 2 other variables

Tags: php

I'm starting a magazine which has 3 editions. UK, US, and European. Each will be published online at different times, therefore each has a different issue number.

So I want to create a way of selecting which issue goes with which edition, but I don't know how to join these 2 parts together. The code I'm using is:

```
<?php
$this_edition = "UK";
?>

<?php
$UK_issue = "1";
$US_issue = "3";
$EU_issue = "2";
?>

<?php
$this_issue = // The Issue Relating to This Edition
?>
```

What I want to do here is basically call the issue number ( 1/3/2 ) which relates to the `$edition` I'm udating, in this case, UK.

So essentially : `$this_issue = $edition_issue`

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Using arrays would make more sense imo.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your problem, but isn't it just enough to use $this_edition with the value of $*_issue?

Comment: Meaning? I basically just want to select the issue number based on the Edition!

Comment: @maio290, the script isn't always going to be `UK`. I load that based on the Issue type. I want to say something like $this_issue = `$edition_issue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is possible...

```
$this_issue = ${$this_edition.'_issue'};
```

But it's way better to use the solution suggested by pr1nc3.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested it this way and it's working fine, so I'll go with it. I only know basic PHP so I'd like to keep it simple with something that I understand. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

How about an array so you have `keys` and `values` to match?

For example `$magazine = [1 => 'UK', 2 => 'US', 3 => 'EU'];`

```
Array
(
    [1] => UK
    [2] => US
    [3] => EU
)
```

Your array keys (issues) match the country(edition)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Associative Array as shown below.

```
<?php
$this_edition = "UK";
$edition['UK'] = 1;
$edition['US'] = 2;
$edition['EU'] = 3;
$this_issue = $edition[$this_edition];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an array so you have keys and values to match?

```
$magazine = array(1 => 'UK', 2 => 'US', 3 => 'EU');
$issue=1;
echo $magazine[$issue];
```

output will be

```
UK
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already got your answer, But just want to show you another way if you need to hold more details about your editions and issues in an array.

```
    <?php
    $this_edition = "UK";

    $editions = array("UK"=>array("name"=>"UK Edition","value"=>1), "US"=>array("name"=>"US Edition","value"=>2), "EU"=>array("name"=>"EU Edition","value"=>3));

    echo $this_issue = $editions[$this_edition]["name"];
    ?>
```

**Output: UK Edition**

If you keep your information inside mapped array, you will be able to receive them very easily at any point you need.